# ninja, kati in aosp - How to print all executed commands when executing 'mm' or 'mmm' or 'mmma'

Tags: android-source

How to show all executed bash commands when building only one project from aosp using 'mm' ? (ie. to get the same output as 'mm showcommands' on older aosp version with make builder)

Answer (score -1):

from build/make/Usage.txt

```
Targets that adjust an existing build:
showcommands                Display the individual commands run to implement
                            the build
```

try

```
$ mm showcommands
```

Comment: In my question I have asked how to get output similar to 'mm showcommands' and you wrote 'try: mm showcommands' ;) - show commands do not show anymore all gcc javac etc.. bash executed commands. It was working in Android 5 and 6 but not in kati ninja builds. Hence I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry :)

The build document has been updated: [Usage.txt](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/Usage.txt). Does `$OUT/verbose.log.gz` have the information you seek?

Comment: Mike thank you, it does. I realized just now that out/verbose.log.gz is not in Android8 but is created in Android 10.